# Applet loading problem with Win2003 Terminal Server

Tags: java, applet, windows-server-2003

Applet loading seem to fail with JAVA 1.6  to error  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)

I believe this is related to limited security of user accounts under Win2003. Any ideas? The site is trusted.   It works with ADMINISTRATOR user.

Answer (score 1):

DiskQUOTA was full.